# How to stop timer on server, when user disconnect? (Node.js/socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, socket.io

On the server there is a timer, when it starts, the countdown starts, but when the user leaves the page, the timer continues to run and is triggered when the user is no longer on the page. How can I stop this timer before the user leaves the page or when it already leave?

```
    //Timer function
    function startTimer() {
        console.log("Timer statrted!");
        var countdown = 15000;
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Timer done!");
        }, 15000);
    }

    socket.on("get data", function() {
         io.to(room_name).emit("data");
         //call timer
         startTimer(); //"Timer started!", "user disconnected", (after 15s) "Timer done!"
     });



     socket.on("disconnect" ,function(){
         console.log("user disconnected");   
     });
```

I tried to stop `clearTimeout()` in `socket.on("disconnect")` or `socket.on("disconnecting")`  but they do not work on the current user who has already left the page... They triggered only for another users...

Comment: you need to store timerID and use the same in clearTimeout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store timerID and use the same in `clearTimeout`

```
var socketTimer;
    function startTimer() {
            console.log("Timer statrted!");
            var countdown = 15000;
            socketTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("Timer done!");
            }, 15000);
        }

    function stopTimer (){
        clearTimeout(socketTimer);
    }
        socket.on("get data", function() {
             io.to(room_name).emit("data");
             //call timer
             startTimer(); //"Timer started!", "user disconnected", (after 15s) "Timer done!"
         });



         socket.on("disconnect" ,function(){
             console.log("user disconnected");   
             stopTimer();
         });
```

Answer (score -1):

Anyway logic should be incapsulated. For example (not for this task).

```
const MakeTimer = (ms = 3000) => {
  return () => {
    let socketTimer;
    const startTimer = (cb) => {
      // console.log("Timer started!");
      socketTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        // console.log("Timer done and will be restarted.");
        if (cb) { cb() }
        startTimer(cb);
      }, ms);
    };
    const stopTimer = () => clearTimeout(socketTimer);
    return { startTimer, stopTimer };
  };
};

const timer1 = MakeTimer(10000)();
const timer2 = MakeTimer()();

module.exports = function(io){

  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    timer1.startTimer(() => console.log('hello 1st timer'));
    timer2.startTimer(() => console.log('hello 2nd timer'));

    socket.on("disconnect" ,function(){
       console.log("User disconnected");
       timer1.stopTimer();
       timer2.stopTimer();
     });
  });
};
```

Comment: Sorry, not for this task. About timers generally.